# cross-origin resolve in firefox but not in chromium

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm dealing with the problem of cross-origin in javascript when i do a http request, i resolve the problem with CORS, my webserver put the headers: allow-origin and my browser (firefox) accept the request.

But testing my js in Chromium i have found with this message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8111/. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

To whe Chromium browser there are another way? not enough with the server response put the headers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to access cross domain ajax request